# What is the correct interpretation of mass-energy equivalence?

Tags: special-relativity, mass-energy

In this essay https://digitalcommons.calpoly.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1017&context=phil_fac
the author puts forth some different interpretations of $E = mc^2$ and comes to the conclusion that mass and energy are different properties that can convert between each other. But I've also heard that mass is actually a form of energy and there is no conversion. Is there an agreed upon interpretation of $E = mc^2$?

Comment: The latter is a more standard interpretation, mass is a type of energy which can be converted into kinetic energy or wave energy, etc... Can you point more directly to the section which the author claims otherwise, my guess is that they are simply explaining that energy can take different forms, mass being one of them, and you can convert between those forms.

Comment: When organized into four vectors, where the "length" of the four vector is the invariant mass, all things become clear , see this answer of mine https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/224938/what-is-the-basic-concept-of-four-dimensions-in-physics/224955#224955 , and this link http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In relativity space and time are unified into a single overall concept called spacetime. Mathematically, spacetime is represented by a 4 dimensional manifold, with 1 dimension of time and 3 dimensions of space.

Spacetime has a notion of “distance” called the “spacetime interval” which combines spatial distances and temporal durations in a way that all reference frames agree on. Such invariant quantities, like the spacetime interval, are crucially important precisely because all frames agree on them.

Many other quantities have a similar relationship in relativity, including in particular energy and momentum. Energy and momentum are unified into the “four momentum” in the same way as time and space are unified into spacetime.

For the four-momentum the invariant quantity is the mass. Different frames will disagree on the energy and the momentum, but they will all agree on the mass. This invariant notion of mass is crucially important in particle physics and is the standard quantity that physicists mean when they refer to “mass”.

This invariant mass is defined as $$m^2 c^2=E^2/c^2-p^2$$ As you can see, for $p=0$ this simplifies to the famous $E=mc^2$ and for $m=0$ it simplifies to the photon’s $E=pc$. Furthermore, it is clear that energy and mass are not the same thing, even in natural units where $c=1$.

However, there is also no conversion of one into the other. An isolated system has a conserved energy and a conserved momentum, so the mass of the system is also conserved. The issue is that the mass is not additive. The mass of a system is generally larger than the sum of the masses of the constituents.

So in an electron-positron annihilation the resulting system of two photons has the same mass as the original electron-positron system. Mass of the system has not been converted into energy because both the mass and energy of the system are conserved and were the same before and after. The sum of the rest masses is not the mass of the system.

Comment: "Mass of the system has not been converted into energy because both the mass and energy of the system are conserved and were the same before and after."

I think your exposition here is somewhat misleading. For a Z->diphoton system, the mass of either photon is zero, and energy has been converted from the rest mass of the Z into the kinetic energy of the photons. Rest mass is a very specific type of energy that is localized in spacetime, it is characteristically different from the invariant mass construction and there is some sort of conversion occurring in particle decays.

Comment: @CasualScience the mass of either photon alone is zero, but mass of the system of both photons is the same as the mass of the system that produced them. I already covered essentially this example in the answer

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use the complete equation:$$E = \sqrt{c^2p^2 + m^2c^4}$$ If the mass is at rest in our frame: $$E = mc^2$$
Now suppose an explosion, so that fragments of that mass goes everywhere, and electromagnetic radiation also be part of the output. Then, for conservation of energy, the sum of the momentum of all that stuff have to be considered. And for that the first equation is important.

As it has $2$ terms, because the momentum is not zero, the second term must be smaller than the original $mc^2$. And we can say that part of mass was transformed in energy. Maybe more appropriated is to say: now part of the energy is mass and part is momentum.

Answer (score 1):

I skimmed through the paper and I think the author seems to have some weird predefined notion of "Energy" as some spooky ephemeral material. Energy is an invariant of physical systems through time propagation. In other words, it's a quantity that we know won't change as time evolves.

Consider an analogy with "purchasing power". Let's pretend we freeze the cost of all goods and the exchange rate between all currencies into perpetuity (e.g. 1 euro is always 1.1 dollars, a house is always 300k dollars, etc...) and purchases and currency exchanges can happen with no fees whatsoever.

In this system, purchasing power is the analog of energy, it is an invariant of financial transactions. For instance, if you buy a house, you can trade it for a car + cash and end up with the same amount of cash you'd have if you just bought the car outright. Your purchasing power never changes, it only is exchanges into different forms. If you start out with all your purchasing power in US dollars, you could exchange those dollars for a house or a car or euros. Any of those assets would be an analog of mass.

No, dollars are not identical to purchasing power, but they represent some amount of purchasing power. If you have some amount of dollars you can use a formula to let you quantify the purchasing power of those dollars in some units. If we choose units of purchasing power to be "house equivalents", then an analogous equation to $E=mc^2$ would be

$$ PP = \frac{1}{300,000} D.$$

The equation above tells us how to translate from purchasing power ($PP$), represented in units of number of houses, to dollars. Notice the form is identical to $E=mc^2$ with the conversion factor $c^2 = \frac{1}{300,000}$.

In the same way, energy is an invariant of time propagation, it's not something that can be generated or destroyed, only transformed into different forms. One form energy can take is mass, and Einstein's relation tells us how to convert from some amount of mass to the amount of energy stored in the mass of the system (in our analogy, how to go from some specific currency to raw purchasing power). Knowing that formula, and, for instance, the formula for how to convert from motion to "kinetic energy" will allow us to calculate how much motion we can "purchase" for some amount of mass.

The formula is really an exchange rate between the units we use for mass and the units we use for energy. Mass is a way energy can be stored, one form energy can take. Through various processes, energy taking the form of mass can be transformed into, e.g. energy taking the form of photons or, e.g. energy taking the form of relative motion between two systems (kinetic energy).